# SetState doesn't update widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want the image to get bigger and to opacity 0 with animation
I tried `setState()` in two functions `_onpre()` and `Future.delayed` to change size and opacity of image but it doesn't change the widgets

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class splatch extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'splatch';
  @override
  _splatchState createState() => _splatchState();
}

class _splatchState extends State<splatch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double _height =  300;
    double _width = 3;


    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        _height = 40;
        _width = 40;
      });

    });

    _onpre() {
        setState(() {
          _height = 40;
        });
    }

    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
            AnimatedContainer(duration: Duration(microseconds: 100),
              height: _height,
              child:Container(
                child: Image.asset('images/rond1.png'),
              ),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed your code.

Some important parts:

- Don't add function inside the `build` widget.
- To animation work you need a `trigger`. In this method i used a `ElevatedButton`

```dart
class splatch extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'splatch';
  @override
  _splatchState createState() => _splatchState();
}

class _splatchState extends State<splatch> {
  late Size size;
  double _height = 300;
  double _width = 3;

  _anim2() async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        _height = 40;
        _width = 40;
      });
    });
  }

  _anim1() {
    setState(() {
      _height = 500;
      _width = 500;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
              height: _height,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _anim1();
              },
              child: Text("Animation 1"),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _anim2();
              },
              child: Text("Animation 2"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the very basics of how setState((){}) works, whenever you change a variable with the help of set-state, it finds the widgets using it and marks them dirty and these dirty widgets are rebuilt with the help of build function and in this process, it is called several times. Hence put your initializing code in initState always.

** Fixed your class name too

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class Splatch extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'splatch';
  @override
  _splatchState createState() => _splatchState();
}

class _splatchState extends State<Splatch> {
  Size size;
  double _height, _width;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    _height = 300;
    _width = 3;
  }

  _onpre() {
    setState(() {
      _height = 40;
    });
  }

  futureCode() async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        _height = 40;
        _width = 40;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(microseconds: 100),
          height: _height,
          child: Container(
            child: Image.asset('images/rond1.png'),
          ),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```